# Server 2008 server won't sync time with domain controller

Tags: windows-server-2003, windows-server-2008

I have two Server 2008 machines on a network (a virtual network; they are both VMs running in VMware Server). One server is a Full Server 2008 installation, and was the first DC I installed. The second server is running Server Core and is also a DC. (This is a test network that I am using for a specific project.)

The problem is that the time/date on the Server Core machine is apparently not syncing up with the other server. I've tried

```
w32tm.exe /resync /nowait
```

and have also tried

```
w32tm /config /update /syncfromflags:DOMHIER
```

and then trying to resync again, but neither seems to work. I'm still getting a completely different time/date on the Server Core machine.

Any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: Are you getting any errors listed in the logs?  What are they set to sync to?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you configured the VMWare to not push the host time to your VM's?  The default behavior of Virtual Services is to have the VM's get their time/date from the VM Host...

Here is [an article](http://www.vmware.com/support/gsx3/doc/tools_cfg_win_gsx.html#wp1054959) I found using a search that talks about enabling/disabling time sync with the host...

Comment: Thanks, it was a VMware issue. I installed VMware Tools, and set it to sync time with the guest OS, and that fixed the problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Have you gone through this KB article?

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/816042